# Remove/Hide Rows which has zero values in Matrix report of SSRS

Tags: matrix, reporting-services, ssrs-2012, sql-server-data-tools

My sample dataset looks like below

| Product | Qty | Denomination |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 0 | 100 |
| A | 0 | 1000 |
| A | 1 | 5000 |
| B | 0 | 100 |
| B | 0 | 1000 |
| B | 0 | 5000 |

I am using below matrix design

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XGOcz.png)

Current Result:

| Product | 100 | 1000 | 5000 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| B | 0 | 0 | 0 |

Expected Result:

Requirement is to not display the record which has all the values as zero.

| Product | 100 | 1000 | 5000 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 0 | 0 | 1 |

Note: I cannot do this data filtration at DB level since I am using 2 different datasets for my matrix and I am using lookup function to get the data.

Thank you in advance!!

Comment: Without seeing how the underlying datasets and the lookup function it's hard to answer. Your dataset example looks like a complete set to me. Anyway you could try setting the row hidden property to `=SUM(Fields!Qty.Value, "Product") = 0` . `"Product"` is the name of your rowgroup

Comment: That was lucky ! : I'll add it as an answer so yo can mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing how the underlying datasets and the lookup function it's hard to answer. Your dataset example looks like a complete set to me. Anyway you could try setting the row hidden property to

```
=SUM(Fields!Qty.Value, "Product") = 0
```

"Product" is the name of your rowgroup